# RecyclerView Single Item ID

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Ehi, i'm modding an example app i found on the Internet. (learn2crack)
I want to get the ID of a single row in my ReclycerView. Here's the code.

Main

```
    private void initViews(){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    ArrayList<AndroidVersion> androidVersions = prepareData();
    DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersions);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Here i need the ID of the clicked row",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recycler, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean a){

        }

    });

}
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> prepareData(){

    ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<android_version_names.length;i++){
        AndroidVersion androidVersion = new AndroidVersion();
        androidVersion.setAndroid_version_name(android_version_names[i]);
        androidVersion.setAndroid_image_url(android_image_urls[i]);
        android_version.add(androidVersion);
    }
    return android_version;
}
```

Adapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions;
private Context context;


public DataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_versions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_versions = android_versions;

}

@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.tv_android.setText(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_version_name());
    Picasso.with(context).load(android_versions.get(i).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(viewHolder.img_android);
    viewHolder.tv_android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View argi) {
            //Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_versions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tv_android;
    ImageView img_android;
    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        tv_android = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_android);
        img_android = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_android);
    }
}
```

As you can see, i did some change. The beahviour i'm trying to implemente is this:
When i click on one of the ReclyclerView button i want to print its "id"(the same thing i used in the adapter, that now is behind comment.
I want to Load a different recyclerview for every click / category. So i'm gonna need a switch-case, but ofc i need to get every single ID from the recyclerview.
If i use the "adapter version" it works, every click displays "1", "2" and so on. But i need this to work on main, so i can call InitViews() again, or call a modified version of it.
I'm looking for something like: int id1=recycleritem.getid(); 
Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `OnTouch` event on the RecyclerView itself.

Set up an `OnClick` on the view in `onBindViewHolder`. When it is fired, call back to the `Activity` with the row of the touched item.

Create the adapter with the interface

```
    MyAdapter adp=new MyAdapter(new MyAdapter.InterfaceCommands() {
        @Override
        public void OnItemPressed(int position) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

Incomplete Example Adapter.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.VH> {

    public MyAdapter(InterfaceCommands i) {
        MyCommands = i;
    }

    public interface InterfaceCommands {

        public void OnItemPressed(int position);

    }

    private InterfaceCommands MyCommands;

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyAdapter.VH holder, final int position) {

        // Set Up ViewHolder pattern
        // ....

        holder.containerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

                MyCommands.OnItemPressed(position);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post me a sample? Or a link?
Thanks
I've no idea how to call back the activity

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks :) 
But...i can't call a function declared in MainActivity, right?

Comment: You do it by passing the interface into the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface called ItemClickListener

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity, and keep a reference of adapter input

```
private ArrayList<AndroidVersion> android_version;

....
....

@Override
public void onClick(int position) {
    AndroidVersion version = android_version.get(position);
    // do your task with retrieved AndroidVersion
}
```

Change the adapter constructor like below

```
new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),androidVersions, itemClickListener);
```

Inside the DataAdapter class

```
viewHolder.tv_android.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View argi) {
            //Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onClick(i);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm still having some issue following your code...

AndroidVersion version = android.get(position);
                                                ^this android, returns an error to me.

I'm trying come alternative solution, but still can't solve it.
Any idea?

Comment: I have edited my answer.. It must be android_version.get(position).